# Spring Boot 2.7.8, latest ElasticSearch Cluster?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Hello dear community,

I am in the process of upgrading Spring Boot from 2.3.x to **2.7.8** and wanted to ask what is the highest Elastic version currently supported? I am currently using an ElasticSearch as well as the ElasticSearch-Rest-Client in version 7.6.2. Spring-Data-Elasticsearch I am currently using version 4.0.0 with JDK 8.

The goal would be to first update to Spring Boot 2.7.8 and then to > 3 incl. JDK 17 to get to ElasticSearch 8.x.

Unfortunately, after updating to Spring Boot 2.7.8, I now have the problem that my Elastic no longer seems to be compatible. Hence the question, which Elastic version do you recommend with Spring Boot 2.7.8? Would be very grateful for any help! :)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.IndexOperations.create(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.document.Document)'

The error is currently thrown.

Updating Spring Boot from 2.3 to 2.7.8.

Answer (score 0):

First, the versions:

When you check https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/reference/elasticsearch/versions.html, Spring Boot 2.7 was pulling Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.4.x which is built against Elasticsearch 7.17.

The exact version, when checking https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.7.8/spring-boot-dependencies-2.7.8.pom:

- Spring Boot 2.7.8
- Spring Data 2021.2.7 which means Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.4.7
- Elasticsearch 7.17.8

Second, your error:
the parameter for the `create` method changed from `Document` to `Map<String, Object>` in 4.2.